# Can I bring compressed air cans in the airport?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, legal, airport-security

I'm buying [this](https://www.ple.com.au/ViewItem.aspx?InventoryItemId=607276) for an overseas friend.

I was wondering if I could bring compressed air cans through the airport considering they come with warnings such as

> Warning: Flammable/Combustible when exposed to naked flame or stored in an area where temperatures exceed 50° C

I know this might be dependent on the airlines, so I'll go ahead and say I'll be flying with either Malaysia Airlines or Jetstar.

Comment: IMO you want to edit the question because noone stops you to bring air cans to the *airport*. AFAIK there is nothing you can't bring to an airport you couldn't bring to a mall or similar.

Comment: FYI there are both inflammable and non-inflammable compressed air cans. All compressed gasses are restricted for air travel/shipment, but the non-inflammable ones are very good choice from a general safety standpoint.

Comment: What if you bring them empty and pump some air into them after you arrive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the TSA website, compressed cylinders are not allowed:

http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items#9

Section:

> Disabling Chemicals & Other Dangerous Items
>
> Fire extinguishers and other compressed gas cylinders **Allowed: NO**

This doesn't mean the airline doesn't have specific requirements, but assuming you are leaving from the US it's TSA that you have to get through first before dealing with the airline.

Comment: I am pretty sure that what is meant by "gas cylinder" is [this](https://i.imgur.com/uVYIVqw.jpg), not [that (aerosol cans)](https://i.imgur.com/HdyOYBQ.jpg). Nevertheless, the [DOT seems to allow it](http://phmsa.dot.gov/safetravel/aerosols). They do not mention compressed air specifically, but they state that flammables are not allowed, which as I understand it, allows compressed air since it is not directly flammable (even though the propellant is). Correct me if I am wrong, but most (if not all) aerosol propellants are inherently flammable; only the actual product may be non-flammable.

Comment: But watch out, most compressed air cans do not actually contain air, but a mixture of propanol, butane and other highly flammable gases, since they compress much better than plain air.

Comment: This TSA blog specifies that compressed air cans are explicitly not allowed, in reference to air horns: http://blog.tsa.gov/2012/02/travel-tips-for-fans-traveling-to-super.html

Answer (score 0):

From the link in Green Chili's post:

Flammable Items     Carry-on?   Checked?
Aerosol (any except for personal care or toiletries in limited quantities)  NO  NO

This is a flammable aerosol (read the description, the propellant is a hydrocarbon), it's not personal care or a toiletry, it's not permitted.